# Создал проект в Visual Studio 2010 для С, но он не воспринимает код С, в чем проблема?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Students
{
    char first_name[15];
    int score[5];
    float avg;
};

struct Subject
{
    char subj[15];
};

float Average(int mass[5])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sum += mass[i];
    }
    float avg = sum / 5;
    return avg;
}

main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");   //чтобы выводило по-русски
    system("chcp 1251");    //чтобы небыло кракозябр при выводе фамилий
    system("cls");          //

    int x = 0;
    printf("Введите количество студентов: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    struct Students *stud;
    stud = (struct Students*)malloc(x * sizeof(struct Students));
    struct Subject sbj[5] = {"Математика", "Философия", "ОАиП", "Экономика", "Логика"};

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        printf("\nФамилия студента: ");
        scanf("%s",&stud[i].first_name);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("%s: ", sbj[j].subj);
            scanf("%d", &stud[i].score[j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        stud[i].avg = Average(stud[i].score);
    }

    FILE *file;
    if (file = fopen("file.txt", "a+")) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            fprintf(file, "\n %s ", stud[i].first_name);
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                fprintf(file, " %d", stud[i].score[j]);
            }
            fprintf(file, " Средний балл: %4.2f", stud[i].avg);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d. %s ", i + 1, stud[i].first_name);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d", stud[i].score[j]);
        }
        printf(" Средний балл: %4.2f", stud[i].avg);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: А в чём конкретно проблема? `main()` без описания типа возвращаемого значения не катит, C со времён K&R стал намного строже.

Answer (score 4):

Вы точно дали ему расширение `.c`, а не `.cpp`? :)

Если его компилировать как C++, то тут компилятор более строгий, и не пропускает `main` без возвращаемого значения и `setlocale` без объявления.

```
float avg = sum / 5;
```

То, что в этой строке происходит **целочисленное** деление (так что это будет следующей ошибкой, которую вы будете искать), компилятор тоже предупреждает.

Компилятор C обо всем этом предупреждает, но компилирует.

И еще -

```
if (file = fopen("file.txt", "a+"))
```

Это круто :), но, честное слово, лучше не полениться и написать

```
if (NULL != (file = fopen("file.txt", "a+")))
```

Это не ошибка, но все же так самому понятнее, что вы тут делаете.

P.S. Не понимаю, честно говоря - компилятор ведь сам пишет все то, что написал вам я (даже неудобно как-то повторять его слова :)) - неужели вы вообще не читаете его сообщения?

Comment: Насчет 'не полениться': разумнее вообще вынести присваивание от 'fopen' из 'if'. А если оставлять исходный вариант, то добавить пару скобок для подавления предупреждения. Ваш вариант с NULL я, честно говоря, использовать бы не стал.

Comment: @alexolut Ну, поскольку его применение ограничено только if'ом. то я бы не придирался :) Но вот закрывать файл надо в любом случае, а ТС это не сделал.